# ERROR CODE 1241 :OPERAND SHOULD CONTAIN 1 COLUMN(S)

Tags: select, max, mysql-workbench, min, operands

My goal is to retrieve all accounts where the balance is greater than zero.

I have two table the tblloancontract and the tblloanpayment.

**tblloancontract** has two columns: `accnum`, and `idmember`.

**tblloanpayment** has: `idpayment`, `balance`, and `accnum` (a foreign key from tblloancontract).

Below is the MYSQL code I have written so far:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tblloanpayment WHERE accnum IN
(SELECT MAX(idpayment), tblloanpayment.accnum, MIN(tblloanpayment.balance)
FROM tblloanpayment JOIN tblloancontract ON tblloanpayment.accnum=tblloancontract.accnum
GROUP BY idmember) AND balance > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want all accounts where the lowest balance is greater than 0?  In that case, why do you need the `tblloancontract` table at all?

```
SELECT tlp.accnum, MIN(tlp.balance) 
  FROM tblloanpayment tlp
  GROUP BY tlp.accnum
  HAVING MIN(tlp.balance) > 0;
```

That's not really a very good way to store loan information.  The "contract" table should have the initial balance and the current balance, and the "payment" table should have the payment amounts.